# How to populate a list of custom user controls with the contents of a bound property

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Say I have the following on my viewmodel:

```
Public ObservableCollection<SubItem> SubItems
```

Now, each SubItem has the following properties:

```
Public String Part1
Public String Part2
```

Given this, I want a ListBox which displays Part1 and Part2 in editable text boxes, one ontop of the other, for each SubItem in SubItems.

To do this, I have created a SubItemUserControl, which is currently just those two text boxes:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

I have then set the ListBox on the MainWindow control as follows:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubItems}" Grid.Row="2">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:SubItemUserControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This displays two empty text boxes for each SubItem.

What I don't know, is how to bind the two properties in the SubItem to the two text-boxes in the SubItemUserControl.

Comment: Is this a direct copy/paste of your code? The TextBoxes in SubItemUserControl don't have any bindings specified. What happens if you add the bindings? e.g. <TextBox Text="{Binding Part1}"/> <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Part2}"/>

Comment: Besides the missing binding declaration, Part1 and Part2 must also be declared a public properties, not fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Create SubItemModel which implement INotifyPropertyChange Interface:

```
public class SubItem : BindableBase
{
    private string _part1;

    public string Part1
    {
        get
        {
            return _part1;
        }
        set
        {
            _part1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Part1");
        }
    }

    private string _part2;

    public string Part2
    {
        get
        {
            return _part2;
        }
        set
        {
            _part2 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Part2");
        }
    }
}
```

2.Initialize your ObservableCollection collection in yout ViewModel:

```
 private ObservableCollection <SubItem> _subItems;
    public ObservableCollection<SubItem> SubItems
    {
        get
        {
            return _subItems;
        }
        set
        {
            _subItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SubItems ");
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _subItems = new ObservableCollection<SubItem>
        {
            new SubItem{Part1 = "AP1", Part2 = "AP2"},
            new SubItem{Part1 = "BP1", Part2 = "BP2"},
            new SubItem{Part1 = "CP1", Part2 = "CP2"},
        };
    }
```

3.Set your View when Part1 is on top of Part2 and bind your properties:

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubItems}" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="Part1" Text="{Binding Part1}"/>
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="Part2" Text="{Binding Part2}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

4.Implement your BindableBase:

```
public class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
  {
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
        handler(this, e);
    }
  }
}
```